# How can I take geometry from my api in flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I get geometry coordinates from this mongo API in flutter? I'm able to get name, type, description but cordinates.

[image]

```
class Padiglioni {
  final String id;
  final String nome;
  final String area;
  bool check = false;
  Geometry geometry;

  Padiglioni( {
    required this.area,
    required this.id,
    required this.nome,
    required this.check,
    required this.geometry
  });

  factory Padiglioni.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Padiglioni(
        id: json['id'] as String,
        nome: json['nome'] as String,
        area: json['area'] as String,
        check: false,
        geometry: Geometry.fromJson(json['geometry']),


    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you add some ocde so that we can help you. since cordinates is a list you have to use index to get the values ex., model.coordinates[1][0] will fetch you the first value from the first list .

Comment: Please add your codes !!

Comment: i try to edit but stack tell me  that is much code

Answer (score 0):

Thats pretty simply all you have to do is to parse json data from your request

you have two options

1. use builtin serialized json methods
2. use your own dart model classes using jsonToDart [https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/]

ok so all you have to do is to create class of geometry first something like this

class Geometry {
List cordinate;

```
Geometry({this.cordinate});

Geometry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['cordinate'] != null) {
        cordinate = new List<List>();
        json['cordinate'].forEach((v) { cordinate.add(new List.fromJson(v)); });
    }
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.cordinate != null) {
  data['cordinate'] = this.cordinate.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
}
    return data;
}
```

}

class Cordinate {

```
Cordinate({});

Cordinate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    return data;
}
```

}

now after this just give your json object to this function and then you can use it wherever u want

```
Geometry geometry = Geometry.fromJson(jsonResponse['geometry']);
```

Comment: **if its possible to change the response of Api then kindly GO for making it simple one idea but yes its possible with this response too but a little confusing and hard one**

Comment: The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. (Documentation)  Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'. i have this error